Developing a cross Platform PowerPoint AddIn
I want to develop a cross platform PowerPoint Add In (to mainly be used on PowerPoint for Windows and Mac) but I cannot use the JavaScript API, since it doesn't offer certain events, when in Presentation mode. For example I would like to have access to some Event that occurs when going to the next slide like in a VSTO Add In Application.SlideShowNextSlide Event. Is it possible to make such an Add In available on Windows and Mac? are there any good resources to accomplish this?
I already noticed that developing a VSTO Add In would be possible yet it would only be available for Windows, or am I just mistaken there?

VSTO add-ons only for Windows Desktop Office apps. Office JavaScript API offers support across clients/platforms with the concept of "write once, works everywhere".

Yeah I mean I get that but the JavaScript API lacks a lot of capabilities and hasn't been updated or further developed in quite a while now. Is there maybe a way to develop add-ons for Mac specifically using neither JS API nor VSTO but a different technology?

Yes, there is another technology called AppleScript, this is a sort of automation for Outlook or any other application which supports it on Mac. You may create the add-on looking scripts with/without user UI interaction. Standard Outlook on Mac supports it, but the new Outlook doesn't yet. I believe they are planning to add back this support, but who knows: roadmap
